# css animation does not work in firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have created a simple loader with `css`. It works fine in chrome but nor working in firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/sunilmadaan07/4dcaLegc/

Code is as below:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='loader'> 
    <div class='loader--text'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am on Chrome (albeit an older version v43) but it doesn't work.

Comment: It is working fine at my side on chrome.

Comment: Check the browser support here - https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/ Seems like animating the `content` doesn't work in most browsers (they say even in Chrome it works only from v46, so explains why it doesn't work on my Chrome).

Comment: @Harry, have u any idea that why this loader is not wotking in mozilla.

http://codepen.io/codecalm/pen/eppjjM

Answer (score 0):

`Content` animation not working in most of all browser. You can do following using plugins.

```js
$("#randomArea").Loadingdotdotdot({
                  "speed": 400,
                  "maxDots": 5,
                  "word": "Loading"
              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/Loadingdotdotdot/js/jquery.loadingdotdotdot.js"></script>
<div id="randomArea" style="position: relative;">done!</div>
```

**[Reference Link](https://css-tricks.com/loading-dots-plugin/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can achieve the effect using plain JS but i have used jQuery..

**jQUERY**

```
// Simpler, does exactly the same thing:
var i=1;
var txt="Loading";
function go () {
    console.log(i);
    $('.loader--text').text(txt);
    i++;
    txt+=".";
    if(i==5)
    {
    txt="Loading";
    i=1;
    }
    setTimeout(go,1000);
}
go();
```

JSFIDDLE Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/4dcaLegc/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `animation` with `:after` pseudo is not supporting in Firefox, thats why I change some of your code a litter from `content` to `width` on parent element.

Check below snippet:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.loader {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.loader-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:64px;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation: loadertext 3s infinite;
  -moz-animation:loadertext 3s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes loadertext {
  0% {
    width:64px;
  }
  35% {
    width:68px;
  }
  60% {
    width:72px;
  }
  100% {
    width:75px;
  }
}
@keyframes loadertext {
  0% {
    width:64px;
  }
  35% {
    width:68px;
  }
  60% {
    width:72px;
  }
  100% {
    width:75px;
  }
}

.loader-text:after {
  content: "Loading...";
  font-weight: bold;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='loader'>
   
    <div class='loader-text'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```